# Go to my ranking in table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, ranking

I have table in database contain points of players. I have page index.php showing that table:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
  $pageload=intval($_GET['page']);
  if ($pageload==1 || $pageload==""){
      $Lpage=0;
      }
  else {
      $Lpage=($pageload*10)-10;
      }}
else{$Lpage=0;}


  $expects="
SELECT id
     , user_id
     , sum(points) AS points 
  FROM expectation 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY points DESC 
 Limit $Lpage,10
";
  $result_ex=mysqli_query($berikane,$expects);
  $row_ex=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ex);
  do{ 
  $xx=$xx+1;  
  ?>
        <tr>
          <td width="40" height="35" align="center"><?php echo $xx?></td>
          <td width="170" height="35"><?php  
       echo $row_puid['username'];
       ?></td>
          <td height="35" align="center"><a href="Details.php?<?php echo "uid=".$puid ?>"><?php echo $row_ex['points']?></a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php }while ($row_ex = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ex));
        $expects2="SELECT id,user_id,sum(points) AS points FROM expectation GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY points DESC ";
  $result_ex2=mysqli_query($berikane,$expects2);
  $row_ex2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ex2);
  $pcount=mysqli_num_rows($result_ex2); 
  $pcount=$pcount/10;
  $pcount=ceil($pcount);
             ?>
                    <tr>
          <td height="35" colspan="3" align="center"><?php
        for ($pg=1;$pg<=$pcount;$pg++){
            ?> <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $pg ?>" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:18px"><?php echo $pg ?>&nbsp;&nbsp; </a><?php 
            }     
   ?>
```

Now index.php show 10 rows from table and I have to click on number of page to go to that page (1,2,3,..etc)  I want to help user to click on a button then will go to that page in table that contain his ranking.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To get the page number

1. get the current user points
2. count all record that points more than current user points
3. divide it by number of record show on each page

now you should get the page number

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by add this:

```
 do{
      $z=$z+1;
      if($row_ex2['user_id']==$row['user_id']){
        $showpage=$z;
        $showpage=ceil($showpage/10); 
   }}while ($row_ex2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ex2))
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $showpage ?>">show my rank</a>
```